# unity broke after installing emerald

Tags: 14.04, unity

After installing compiz settings and emerald, unity broke in Ubuntu14.04. Desktop just shows wallpaper but unity and unity launcher doesn't appear.
I tried uninstalling compiz and emerald and again install unity. But still it didn't help.

Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

Well you should be careful with the compiz settings. Here is how you reset the unity and compiz settings:

Open terminal the terminal **Ctrl+Alt+t** and reset the compiz settings:

```
sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

Then reset unity:

```
sudo setsid unity
```

Finally reset the unity icons:

```
sudo unity --reset-icons
```

Hopes this helps, and be careful in the future.

Comment: Unable to open terminal. And if tried from tty then I get error display manager X11 not started.

Comment: How about the **Ctrl+Alt+F2** terminal, enter your username and password, run the commands above and do a reboot, `sudo reboot`

Comment: I tired that....but unable to execute dconf reset

Comment: Oh maybe you dont have the dconf installed, try to intall it `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`and then try again

Comment: I already installed it. While running the dconf reset command it gives me error that Display X11 not started

Comment: I did the fresh install